# php adding items to an array that's outside an foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

What I'm trying to do is loop through an array of items and add each of them to my db. After they're added to the db, the 'Add' class' function should return the status and message of each item. I'm trying to add each of these statuses and messages to an `outcome` array that's outside my `foreach` loop and then when the loop completes I'm trying to print the `outcome` array but I keep getting this error:
`Trying to get property of non-object in <b>pathToTheLoop\ScheduleController.php</b> on line <b>38</b><br />` . The line which is specified points to where I'm trying to add the stuff to my `outcome` array.

Anyway, here's my code:

```
$returned = array();
foreach ($dates as $date) {
  $startStr = $date . " " . $start;
  $startDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $startStr);
  $endStr = $date . " " . $end;
  $endDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $endStr);

  $sdl = new Schedule($startDate, $endDate, null);
  $outcome = $sdl->createSlot();
  $returned['status'] = $outcome->status;
  $returned['message'] = $outcome->message;
}
print json_encode($returned);
```

Note that I've tried populating my array with the method above, as well as with the following method:

```
$returned[] = array(
  $status => $outcome->status,
  $message => $outcome->message
);
```

I'm not including the code for the `Schedule` class because I'm fairly certain that it works because stuff I send to add to the db actually gets added and also because if I replace the part where I'm trying to populate the array with a `print // the outcomes` it actually prints it.

**Edit:** When I do `var_dump($outcome);` instead of trying to add the outcomes to `$returned` I get this:

```
array(2) {
  ["status"]=>
  string(7) "success"
  ["message"]=>
  string(62) "New slot added from 2016-10-10 09:00:01 to 2016-10-10 10:00:00"
}
array(2) {
  ["status"]=>
  string(7) "success"
  ["message"]=>
  string(62) "New slot added from 2016-10-17 09:00:01 to 2016-10-17 10:00:00"
}
array(2) {
  ["status"]=>
  string(7) "success"
  ["message"]=>
  string(62) "New slot added from 2016-10-24 09:00:01 to 2016-10-24 10:00:00"
}
array(2) {
  ["status"]=>
  string(7) "success"
  ["message"]=>
  string(62) "New slot added from 2016-10-31 09:00:01 to 2016-10-31 10:00:00"
}
```

Comment: It seems that $outcome is not an object. Could you post the output of var_dump($outcome)?

Comment: Try to print `$outcome` first and see the variables coming from that, and confirm that a `status` and a `message` is displaying...

Comment: I added the output of var_dump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the value of `$outcome` is an array rather than an object so you could try casting the result as an object and that should allow you to use the object notation to access the values.

```
  $outcome = (object)$sdl->createSlot();
  $returned['status'] = $outcome->status;
  $returned['message'] = $outcome->message;
```

or, alternatively use the array notation

```
  $outcome = $sdl->createSlot();
  $returned['status'] = $outcome['status'];
  $returned['message'] = $outcome['message'];
```

Comment: The second part of your answer (array notation) did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just create an array in each array row.

```
$returned[] = array("status" => $outcome->status, "message" =>$outcome->message );
```